# Get calendar events from Calendar (possibly using ActiveDirectory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap

I need to start extracting events in a microsoft calendar.

I've never done this before, so just want pointing in the right direction.

Does anyone know if this is possible using Active directory?
Anyone have any examples of where this has been done before?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: You might edit this question to better explain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory is an authentication system, primarily.  The calendar data would be stored in an application, I imagine Exchange as a guess, if you are using Microsoft technology.

This data is NOT exposed via Active Directory.